# What is the probability that the largest of 3 independent uniformly distributed random variables is greater than the sum of the other two?

Tags: probability, integration, order-statistics

I wanted to solve this using order statistics, therefore, I need to compute: 
$$\mathbb{P}\{X_{(1)}+X_{(2)} < X_{(3)}\}$$
The probability density function of $n$ order statistics is: 
$$n!f(x_1)\cdots f(x_n)$$
Therefore I need to solve the integral 
$$\iiint_{x_1+x_2 < x_3}3!\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2\mathrm{d}x_3$$
Since $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are independent and uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$
To calculate the bounds, I do the following: 
$$\{0<x_1<1\ ,\ 0<x_2<1\ ,\ 0<x_3<1\ ,\ x_1+x_2<x_3\}$$
$$\{0<x_1<\min(1,x_3-x_2) \ ,\ 0<x_2<1\ ,\ 0<x_3<1\}$$
$$\{0<x_1<1, 1<x_3-x_2 \ ,\ 0<x_2<1\ ,\ 0<x_3<1\} \cup \{0<x_1<x_3-x_2, 1>x_3-x_2 \ ,\ 0<x_2<1\ ,\ 0<x_3<1\}$$
$$\{0<x_1<1  \ ,\ 0<x_2<\min(1,x_3-1)\ ,\ 0<x_3<1\} \cup \{0<x_1<x_3-x_2 \ ,\ \max(0, x_3-1)<x_2<1\ ,\ 0<x_3<1\}$$
Which reduces to
$$\{0<x_1<x_3-x_2 \ ,\ 0<x_2<1\ ,\ 0<x_3<1\}$$
This implies that
$$3!\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^{x_3-x_2}\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2\mathrm{d}x_3=0$$
What am I doing wrong? Can I even apply order statistics to this problem or not?

Comment: I'm assuming you have a random sample $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$. Is $n=3$? What's the distribution of the sample?

Comment: @user365239 yes, $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are all independent and uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$

Comment: I didn't check all your calculations, but I assume your problem is that you integrate from $0$ to $x_3 - x_2$, but for $x_3 - x_2 < 0$ you should just integrate from zero to zero.

Comment: @Dominik that is something I try to address in the middle of the question, when trying to find the bounds. I used the strategy followed by Graham Kemp in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029627/how-to-evaluate-this-integral-iiint-y2-4xz-ge-0-mathrmdx-mathrmdy-mat/2029661#2029661

Comment: First split the configuration into 3 cases, depends on whether $X_1, X_2$ or $X_3$ is the largest. Let's say $X_3$ is the largest one, change variable
to $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (\lambda z,\mu z, z)$ with $(\mu,\nu,z) \in [0,1]^3$. the parameter space will be easier to describe in the new coordinates.

Comment: @achillehui Yes, I know that I can calculate this problem by splitting it into three cases, but I would like to use order statistics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint pdf for all three sufficient statistics $(X_{(1)},X_{(2)},X_{(3)})$ is
$$
f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = 3! \cdot \mathbb{1}_{[ 0 \le x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le 1]}.
$$
This is one part you're missing, I think youre integrating incorrectly over regions where your pdf should give zero.

Then the desired probability is
$$
\int 3! \cdot \mathbb{1}_{[ 0 \le x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le 1]} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{[ x_1 + x_2 \le x_3]} \; dx_3 \, dx_2 \, dx_1
$$
and it may be helpful to rewrite this as
$$
\int 3! \cdot \mathbb{1}_{[ 0 \le x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le 1]} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{[0 \le  x_1 + x_2 \le x_3 \le 1]} \; dx_3 \, dx_2 \, dx_1
$$
to get the integral bounds. Can you take it from here? ( I can post more if needed)

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was missing. Now I get two integrals which both yield $1/4$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, and I am also getting 1/2 as final ans

Answer (score 2):

> Which reduces to 
>   $\{0<x_1<x_3−x_2 , 0<x_2<1 , 0<x_3<1\}$

No, it reduces to $\{0<x_1<\min\{x_2,x_3-x_2\}, 0<x_2<\bbox[2pt,border:red 1pt dotted]{x_3}, 0<x_3<1\}$

PS: recalling that $\{x_1<x_2<x_3\}$

Comment: Thanks @GrahamKemp, I always have some trouble with inequalities. I did not notice that last inequality that one needs with order statistics. In any case, the strategy you showed me in one of my questions for finding bounds of integration has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The joint density function of the order statistics $X_{(i)}$ and $X_{(j)}$ when $i<j$ is $$ f_{X_{(i)}, X_{(j)}}\left(x_{i}, x_{j}\right)=\frac{n !}{(n-j) !(j-i-1) !(i-1) !}\left[F\left(x_{i}\right)\right]^{i-1}\left[F\left(x_{j}\right)-F\left(x_{i}\right)\right]^{j-i-1}\left[1-F\left(x_{j}\right)\right]^{n-j} f\left(x_{i}\right) f\left(x_{j}\right) $$
for all $ 0<x_{(i)}<x_{(j)}<1 $.
So, we need to calculate integration:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_1+X_2\leq X_3)=\int_0^{1/2}\int_{x_1}^{1-x_1}\int_{x_1+x_2}^1 (1-x_1-x_2)(1-x_2) dx_3dx_2dx_1 = 1/2
$$